# How do I stop receiving "Remove risky access" emails about Google Scripts I have created?

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script, google-account

I have created a Google Apps Script which I use frequently. I receive regular emails from Google: "Some apps or services that you allowed to access your Google Account have not been verified by Google..."

How do I:

1. Add my script to a Trusted list, or
2. Convince Google that I have acknowledged the risk (to avoid repeat emails)?

I have the same problem with "Sign-in from a new location" emails, which are about work computers that I use over and over. Can I add IP addresses to a trusted list?

Answer (score 0):

To do A and B there are two paths

1. Add the script code to a Google Apps Script project owned by you (the same account used to run the script should be its owner)
2. Create an add-on a ask Google to verify your script.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization

Comment: Thanks Rubén. The first approach hasn't been successful (that's what I currently do). I'll try to have Google verify the add-on, as my colleagues also use the script.